# Ag-grid grid rendering after receiving data from API

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to create a common component on ag-grid that can be used across my application . When i use this common component in some parent component and call the service to get data and pass it to common component my grid is rendering before the data arrives.

i have tried these things till now 
1. ngOnchanges method

```
ngOnChanges(){


     console.log(this.entityData);
         this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
        this.gridOptions = {
          onGridReady: () => {
              this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.entityData);
          }
        };

  }
```

1. common component:

   import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, HostBinding, Input, 
    Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

   import { GridReadyEvent } from 'ag-grid-community';

   import { GridOptions } from 'ag-grid';

   import {  SDSAlertService } from '../../../services/sdsalert.service';

   // import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

   @Component({
     selector: 'apt-entity-grid',
     templateUrl: './entity-grid.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./entity-grid.component.scss'],
     changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
   })

   export class EntityGridComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges{

   @HostBinding('class.ag-grid20-context')
     hasClass=true;

   @Input() public columnDefs:any;

   @Input() public entityData:any;

   @Output() public singleRowData = new EventEmitter();

   @Output() public showForm = new EventEmitter();

   public rowSelection;
     public previousRowSelected: any;
     public selectedRow: boolean;
     public rowData:any;
     public gridOptions: GridOptions;
     response = [];

   constructor(private sdsData:SDSAlertService) {

   ```
   this.selectedRow  = false;
   this.showForm.emit(false);
   this.rowSelection = "multiple";
   ```

   }

   ngOnInit() {

   ```
   console.log(this.entityData);
   ```

   }

   ngOnChanges(){

   ```
   console.log(this.entityData);
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
   this.gridOptions = {
     onGridReady: () => {
         this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.entityData);
     }
   };
   ```

   }

   onRowClicked(event: any) {

   ```
   var selectedDataStringPresentation:[] ;
   const selectedNodes = event.api.getSelectedNodes()  
   const selectedData = selectedNodes.map( function(RowNode) { return RowNode.data })
   this.singleRowData.emit(event);

   if(event.node.isSelected()){
     this.singleRowData.emit(event);
     event.node.setSelected(false, false);
   } else {
     event.node.setSelected(true);
   }

   selectedDataStringPresentation = selectedDataStringPresentation + selectedData;
   if(selectedData.length === 0 || selectedData.length > 1) {
     this.showForm.emit(false);
   } else {
     this.showForm.emit(true);
   }
   ```

   }

   onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
       params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();

   }

   onCellClicked(event: any) {
       console.log('cell', event); 
     }

   onSelectionChanged(event: any) {
       console.log('selectionchange', event); 
     }

   }

   2. parent component

      Alerts

      ```
        <apt-entity-grid [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
                         [entityData]="rowData" 
                         (singleRowData)="rowSelected($event)" 
                         (showForm)="showForm = $event" >
        </apt-entity-grid>

      </div>
      ```

   import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, HostBinding, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

   import { GridReadyEvent } from 'ag-grid-community';

   import {  SDSAlertService } from '../../services/sdsalert.service';

   import { reduce, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

   import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

   import { EntityDataService } from '../../services/entity-data.service';

   import { EntityDetailsService } from '../../services/entity-details.service';

   @Component({
     selector: 'apt-alert',
     templateUrl: './alert.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./alert.component.scss'],
     changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
   })

   export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {

   @HostBinding('class.ag-grid20-context') hasClass = true;
     public columnDefs: any;
     public rowData:any;
     public title: string;
     public submitted: boolean;
     public alertControllerEntityDetails: any;

   form: FormGroup;

   response = [];

   constructor( private fb:FormBuilder,

   ```
   private entityData:EntityDataService,
   private entityDetails:EntityDetailsService,
   private sdsAlertService: SDSAlertService) {

   this.submitted = false;
   this.alertControllerEntityDetails = this.entityDetails.alertEntity
   this.columnDefs = this.alertControllerEntityDetails.columnDefs;

   this.sdsAlertService.listAlerts().subscribe(r => {
     if (r) {
       this.response.push(...r)
       console.log( this.response);
     } else {
       // clear messages when empty message received
       this.response = [];
     }
   });
   this.rowData = this.response;


   console.log(this.response);
   this.sdsAlertService.getConfiguration().subscribe(r => {
   if (r) {
   console.log(r);
   } else {
   // clear messages when empty message received
   console.log( r);
   }
   });
   ```

   }

   ngOnInit() {

   ```
   this.form = this.fb.group({
     scid: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$')]],
     wsid: ['', [Validators.required,  Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$')]],
     contact: ['', [Validators.required,  Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]],
     walkieTalkie: ['', [Validators.required,  Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$')]]
   });
   ```

   }

   get alertFormControls() {
       return this.form.controls;
     }

   public rowSelected(event: any): void { 
       this.form.setValue(event.data);
     }

   save() {
       this.submitted = true;
       console.log('form', this.form.value );

   }

   }

   3. my service

   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { StateService } from '@airport/portal-shared';
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

   export class AlertRowData {
     owner: string;
     code: string;
     desc: string;
     summary: string;
     severity: string;
     category: number;
     alertType: string;
     id:string;
     acknowledgeable:boolean;
     airport:any;
     customerId:string;
     dataId:string;
     description:string;
     displayable:boolean;
     externalCode:string;
     metaInfo:string;
     products:string;
   }

   @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class SDSAlertService {
     constructor(private http: HttpClient, private stateService: StateService) {}

   listAlerts(): Observable {
       return this.http.get(`/sds/data/v2/alert/list/${this.stateService.getAirport().id}`);
     }

   getConfiguration(): Observable<[]> {
       return this.http.get<[]>('/aodb/services/environment/config/user/SDS');
     }
   }

how i can render the grid when the data arrives,right now data arrives at later point. Also when i run it giving break point the grid seems to be render due to delay.

Comment: try.. send empty data to shared component with ag-grid, and then in the ngOnChange update value..... another way maybe works cant, checkout is to put an ngIf, to hide the grid and when gets the data from service and send to components change the ngIf value. Hope Helps.

Comment: thanks, i have found a solution. using async pipe and rowData as obdervable its working.